# Find expiration date of a certificate file which I do not have installed

Tags: windows-server-2012, certificate, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm looking for a way to find the expiration of a certificate file (either .pfx or .cer) without installing it.

I have access to read the file but can not install it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uh... double-click the *.cer file.  Feast your eyes on the part that says "Valid from x/x/x to x/x/x"

This does not require installing the cert.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Welp, sometimes I over think the solution. Thanks! Needless to say, this is exactly what I am looking.

Comment: I would like to know an automated way to do this, as we're using PowerShell DSC to install our certs and I want to know if the file is a newer version than the one installed, so I can tell if it needs to be replaced or not. Right now we simply check if the cert exists on the server or not to determine if it needs to be installed, but that will not be enough once the cert expires on the server and we've updated the file to a newer "version".